# Why emacsclient can't find socket after executing 'emacs --daemon'

Tags: emacs

It is so confusing that emacsclient said it can't find socket just after executing `emacs --daemon` in bash:

```
$ ps aux | grep emacs
shiangro         1744   0.0  0.0  2432784    604 s000  S+    1:03下午   0:00.00 grep emacs
$ /usr/local/bin/emacs --daemon
("emacs")
Starting Emacs daemon.
Restarting server
$ /usr/local/bin/emacsclient -t
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

I have this settings in my .emacs:

```
(server-start)
(setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs.d/server")
```

and it works,the server file `~/.emacs.d/server/server` was just there,but emacsclient say it can't find socket,so annoying that I have to tell him the socket file using the `-s` option.

I find this thorny problem while I want let emacs runing as a daemon after everytime rebooting(start) systerm by using crontab's `◎reboot` special strings.

In this case ,cron successfully started the emacs server and the server file `~/.emacs.d/server/server` was also there, but later when I started a terminal and tried to `emacsclient -t` ,it failed and complained can't find socket file!

Although I can bypass this problem by using `-s ~/.emacs.d/server/server` everytime I excute emacsclient,or alias emacsclient as `emacsclient -s ~/.emacs.d/server/server` ,but is ther a better way to comfort my heart?

**Backgroud:**

system: Mac OS X 10.9.2

emacs: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 installed by homebrew

Comment: You're expecting emacsclient to automagically know a value which only exists in the Emacs server to which you wish to connect! The simplest thing is to not change `server-socket-dir`. If you do change it, it's only natural that you'll also need to tell emacsclient.

Answer (score 16):

Finding the server socket file is the tricky bit, you can use `lsof` to find it, and then a bit of `grep`-ing to extract the socket path/filename.

```
lsof -c emacs | grep server | grep -E -o '[^[:blank:]]*$'
```

Or on OSX when you expect to be running `/Application/Emacs` you'd change the command name `lsof` is looking for with `-c Emacs`. ie.

```
lsof -c Emacs | grep server | grep -E -o '[^[:blank:]]*$'
```

You could use `cut` instead of the messy filtering `grep` (searching for non-blanks until the line end `[^[:blank:]]*$`)

```
lsof -c Emacs | grep server | cut -c70-
```

Better yet, squish the interspacing and use `cut`'s field chopping.

```
lsof -c Emacs | grep server | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8
```

Now that you have the socket (or it's empty) you can do a conditional start on `emacsclient`, ie.

```
#!/bin/bash 

socket_file=$(lsof -c Emacs | grep server | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8)

if [[ $socket_file == "" ]]; then        
    # Just run Emacs (with any arguments passed to the script)
    # It would be a good idea to parse the arguments and clean/remove
    # anything emacsclient specific. 
    # (ie. -e should be --eval for emacs)
    # note that emacsclient doesn't fix these args for you either
    # when using -a / --alternate-editor

    emacs $@ &

    # or on OSX

    /Application/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $@ &

else

    emacsclient $@ -n -s $socket_file

fi
```

Comment: shouldnt `Emacs` be `emacs`

Comment: It was `/Application/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` in 2017, if it's changed submit an edit.

Comment: On follow up checking.  The answer to your comment is.  **NOPE**.

Comment: This answers the question.  Where it's explicitly asking for Macos/Osx help.

Comment: Many thanks for reading all info thoroughly before commenting.

Comment: there is a chance that Emacs could be alias into emac. And `lsof` may return more than multiple ids if there is more than one daemon is running on the background which cause a failure in the `emacsclient $@ -n -s $socket_file`

Comment: @alper thank you, it sounds possible.  I have not been up to date with the latest changes re: Emacs and Macos.

Comment: Interestingly `$(lsof -c Emacs | grep server | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8)` returns same value for each daemon if there is more than one. Maybe it can be parsed by `head -n1` capturing the first one

Comment: With native compilation enabled, use `$(lsof -c Emacs | grep server | grep --invert-match -e 'eln' | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8 | tr '\012' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1 | head -1)`.

Answer (score 11):

Since you've done:

```
/usr/local/bin/emacs --daemon
```

the server is already started.  So, you don't actually need the:

```
(server-start)
(setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs.d/server")
```

in your .emacs.  When you follow that approach, the server is placed in /tmp/emacs502 (or maybe some other number).  On linux, emacsclient doesn't seem to have trouble finding it there (in that case I'm seeing /tmp/emacs1920), and so "emacsclient -nw" works.  I'm trying it on OSX using HomeBrew, as you are, and I find I have to connect using:

```
emacsclient -nw -s /tmp/emacs502/server
```

(If you used --deamon=name, then you would use "name" instead of "server" in that last line.)

Comment: A possible cause is that you are using the Mac OS X stock emacsclient (version 22) that can't find Emacs 24. Check that your $PATH doesn't look like this: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:` because for homebrew symlinks to work, /usr/local/bin must come _before_ /usr/bin

Comment: thanks dcorking - that was my problem!  I had deleted the stock emacs and installed a new one with homebrew.  needed to delete emacsclient as well

Comment: @WuTheFWasThat - don't need to delete the stock emacs.  Just set the path properly, to look in the homebrew directory first.  (I think that's /usr/local, IIRC.)

Comment: Similar problem, slightly different details: I was starting /Application/Emacs.app, and the emacsclients in my path were, in order `/usr/bin/emacsclient
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient'.   Annoying, because I don't want to put /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin* in my path - that would not be right.  Apps should be self-relative.

Answer (score 3):

emacsclient only finds the emacs server if I run `emacs` from the command line.  If I run emacs from the Ubuntu launcher then `emacsclient` fails to connect to the server.

If you want to use the Emacs daemon instead of the server, define the two environment variables

`export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
 export EDITOR=emacsclient`

You can add these environment variables in either `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

If the ALTERNATE_EDITOR environment variable is empty, then Emacs will run its daemon and connect to it.

Comment: This seems like a goofy solution, but it was the most straightforward to implement and worked on both macOS (set the variable to the full path to emacsclient) and FreeBSD

Answer (score 1):

I think `emacsclient` can look for special file `server` in standard path only, e.g. in `/tmp/emacs1000`. If you change this parameter `server-socket-dir`, then you should tell about it to `emacsclient` by key `-s`.

Comment: is there anyway that we can specify the same server socket dir for both Mac and Linux.

Comment: @nXqd try set environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE in .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

On `macOS`, the `emacs` socket name is calculated as follows:

```bash
export EMACS_SOCKET_NAME="${TMPDIR}/emacs$(id -u)/server"
```

According to
[`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html),
the environment variable `EMACS_SOCKET_NAME` may be set to override the
default.  However, this does not seem to work in a Homebrew environment.  I
have this in my `.bashrc` which works for me:

```bash
export EDITOR="emacsclient --tty"
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR="emacs --no-window-system"

case "$(uname -s)" in
    # ...

    Darwin*)
        export EMACS_SOCKET_NAME="${TMPDIR}/emacs$(id -u)/server"
        export EDITOR="${EDITOR} --socket-name ${EMACS_SOCKET_NAME}"
    ;;
esac
```