# Emacs can't start server

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-8, permissions, localhost

I try to start emacs server on a Windows 8 machine. I downloaded vanilla emacs, and run it using `runemacs.exe`. Then I run `M-x server-start` and the execution of this command takes about 3 minutes, after that there's a `~/.emacs.d/server/server` file with the following contents:

```
127.0.0.1:65118 5868
r@Twzr]X-VjCB`g\&t;U1<bj3X]}6!8XUz~P;{q9'AIj322!w0O1XK[/K4v>ZOK*
```

and emacs server doesn't run: when I try to open a file with `emacsclientw.exe` it says no server.

Apparently emacs tried to start a server but failed. I'm the owner of the `~/.emacs.d` folder.

Comment: Isn't that just an old server file? What happens if you remove it and try again?

Comment: @choroba: tried that -- nope is the file which emacs makes, after 3 minutes of `server-start`.

Comment: Please formulate/add a clear question. Thanks in advance. BTW: Do you have exclusive read permission on `~/.emacs.d/server`? AFAIK emacs considers a server directory where others have read permission as a security risk. Have you read the message-buffer carefully? There might be some problem indicators in it.

Comment: @Tobias: yes I made myself the only owner of the `~/.emacs.d`. Basically I run emacs and try to start a server. Emacs then hangs for 3 minutes, and after that no server is running, instead I have a `~/.emacs.d/server/server` file with the contents as posted.

Comment: Attempt to call `emacs --daemon --debug-init` and tell us what happens. If something errors, try `emacs -Q --daemon --debug-init`

Answer (score 2):

You're using a non-standard socket directory. By default, the sockets are stored in `/tmp/emacsXYZQ` (where `XYZQ` is a number). `emacsclient` cannot be expected to know where you put the sockets, so you need to tell it (if it's not the usual place). You can do this with the `-s` command.

```sh
emacsclient -s ~/.emacs.d/server/server
```

Normally, you'd make this more convienient by adding

```sh
EMACS_SERVER_FILE=~/.emacs.d/server/server
```

to your `~/.profile` and using `emacsclient` normally, but I'm not sure what the windows analog of that would be.

**references:**

- [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148787/why-emacsclient-cant-find-socket-after-executing-emacs-daemon)
- [`emacsclient` options docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options)

Comment: The problem I'm facing is on windows 8. So no `/tmp/emacsXYZQ`. Also I don't set any socket directory -- it is emacs who creates the server file. The problem is not that I can't connect to server, the problem it that I can't start it.

Comment: However both your suggestions -- 1: `emacs -Q --daemon --debug-init` and 2: redefine `server-socket-dir` are fine and sound. I'll try them in a week after I get this computer again (it's a computer of my student, and I'll try it on the next class).

Comment: I think you meant `-f` (`--server-file`), not `-s` (`--socket-name`). Especially since `-s` is not supported on Windows.