# emacs server file empty after starting emacs server

Tags: macos, emacs

I am on OSX, and I have Emacs 24.5 for Mac.
I setup the server path, and start the server in my init.el:

```
  (setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs.d/server")
  (server-start)
```

but when I run `emacsclient somefile`, I have this error:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

I then searched around and non works for me. I then dig into the server file which is `~/.emacs.d/server/server. and I found it is totally empty...
I believe that is the reason that`emacsclient` cannot find the server, any one had similar and knows how to solve it?

thanks

Comment: No, that's not the problem. If anything, you should not set server-socket-dir to anything.

Comment: if i dont set the server-socket-dir, the same issue happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148787/why-emacsclient-cant-find-socket-after-executing-emacs-daemon

Comment: i found this post which does not work for me, i use `-s` to point to the server file and i have the error below:

      Waiting for Emacs...
      -emacs-pid 5106
      -error Unknown&_command:&_/Users/zyuan/.emacs.d/server/server

Comment: Again, there is no reason for you to fiddle with that path. Just start the server, start emacsclient. if you get an error, look at that error.

Comment: i found the issue, the emacsclient i used is the `usr/bin/emacsclient`, not the one with the emacs 24.5

Answer (score 0):

U found the issue, the `emacsclient` I used is the osx's own copy at `usr/bin/emacsclient`, not the one with the emacs 24.5 
I add the line below to my .profile and works now

```
alias emacsclient="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient"
```